# The differences between break , respite and recess

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

What is the difference between the words break, respite and recess in terms of usage ?

Respite means:

A short period of rest or relief from something difficult or unpleasant

Recess means:

A period of time when the proceedings of a parliament, committee, court of law, or other official body are temporarily suspended

Break means:

Interrupt (a continuity, sequence, or course)

source: Oxford Dictionaries

---

What is it called, the short period of rest in an indoor business meeting, workshop, seminar, conference or university lecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A business meeting, workshop, seminar, conference or university lecture would usually be a one-off event (not repeating regularly over time), so when there is time between sessions, I would call that a *break*.
There is also *coffee break*, an activity which repeats but is not scheduled.

In recurring events, such as legal proceedings or school classes, time between a session/class would be called a *recess*. This is more formal than *break*.

As you mentioned, *respite* needs context to determine when it should be used.

(AmE disclaimer)

Comment: can we say "rebel groups has given a respite to the conflict which was taking place through the last one year after deliberations." Because the word conflict suggests an unpleasant thing.

Comment: With a bit of correction, yes. "Rebel groups *have* given a respite *from* the conflict which was taking place through the last year after deliberations."